# how to create queue that will hold pointer to function?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I try to make queue that can receive pointer to function - and i can't find how to do it

this is my code

```
        struct TaskElement
    {
        int id;
        std::function<void()> func;

        void operator()()
        {
            func();
        }
    };

    int main()
    {

        MyMath* myMathElement = new MyMath();

        myMathElement->Print_1();

        Queue<TaskElement> myQueue;


        TaskElement t1;
        t1.id = 1;
        t1.func = myMathElement->Print_1;

        TaskElement t2;
        t2.id = 2;
        t2.func = &myMathElement->Print_2;


        myQueue.push(t1);     Error !!! &': illegal operation on bound member function expression
        myQueue.push(t2);     Error !!! &': illegal operation on bound member function expression

        auto rec1 = myQueue.pop();

        rec1();



        std::cin.get();
    }
```

Comment: This is confusing. You appear to have been on stackoverflow.com long enough to know that all questions of the form "my code doesn't work" must meet all requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. This one fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve] in multiple ways, and nobody should have to point that out to you.

Comment: I learn C++ ... still don't know what is good or not good question .. sorry

Comment: To help you write better questions, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-static member functions needs an object to be called on. By using plain `myMathElement->Print_1` you're not providing any object, just a pointer to a member function.

Either use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to provide the object as the first argument to the function:

```
t1.func = std::bind(&MyMath::Print_1, myMathElement);
```

Or use [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
t1.func = [myMathElement]() { myMathElement->Print_1(); };
```

---

As for your errors, either you get them because of some problem in the `Queue` class (which you haven't shown us), but more likely the errors doesn't come from the `push` calls but rather from the assignments to the `func` member.

You should get them from the assignment because they are not valid assignments. You can't use member functions like that, you must use the address-of operator `&` and full scoping with the *class* (or structure) instead of an object. As shown above with the `std::bind` call, you must use `&MyMath::Print_1`.